# Facebook graph api - Is it possible to get facebook posts from a public page using word filter

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

Is it possible to get feeds from facebook page with query filter?

Egs:

I know feeds from a page is possible using:
 https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/102627429803979/feed

I want
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.9/102627429803979/feed?q=earthquake

Is it possible or not? If yes how?

Thanks.

Comment: No, not possible.

Comment: Ok thank you........